CSS in email working differently in new vs old Outlook
I have been trying to get a button to look a specific way in an email template but am struggling with the width of an a tag on old Outlook (version 2405)
What I want is the a element to fill the td element so that the whole red space is clickable

Red button = td element
Blue border = a element

In new Outlook

In old Outlook

My a element width does not fill the width of the td element.
For some reason the link is clickable on the left side outside of the border but not on the right
Text on span is not white but instead standard link color. This makes the color change when clicked


Here is my code:
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="
    background: red;">
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="
        border: 3px solid blue;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 30px 0;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        cursor: pointer;
        letter-spacing: 0.0625em;">
            <span>
                MY BUTTON
            </span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

I am slowly but surely losing my mind at this point...
I've tried this solution but no luck
I've tried:

changing inline-block to block
changing width
using !important on text color


UPDATE
I modified the accepted answer to make it look like I wanted:
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="
    background: red;">
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="
        border: 3px solid blue;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 30px 0;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        cursor: pointer;
        letter-spacing: 2px;"><!--[if mso]><i style="mso-font-width:245%;" hidden>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</i><span><![endif]-->
            <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255) !important">
                MY BUTTON
            </span>
            <!--[if mso]></span><i style="mso-font-width:245%;" hidden>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&#8203;</i><![endif]-->
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

To me it's good enough!


Older version of outlook wont accept % as an width unit. You have to use px and additional min- and or max-width and width="999px".

Outlook Desktop Windows doesn't support changes to the display. You can visually change the size of the box by using the <td>, but the only way to increase the size of the clickable area is to add inline characters inside the <a>. Since inline characters cannot be set to a width, you have to use something &emsp; which an em space (won't be visible). You can then make that 500% (max) wide, and/or use multiple of them.
mso-text-raise can be used as padding-top and padding-bottom. The first reference should be double the size of the second for equal top and bottom padding.
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" align="center">
<tr>
    <td align="center" style="
    background: #ff0000;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;">
        <a href="https://www.google.com.au" style="background-color:#ff0000; text-decoration: none; padding: 30px 0; color: #ffffff; display:block; border-radius:3px; mso-padding-alt:0;text-underline-color:#ff0000;width:100%;text-align: center;font-size:14px;font-weight:700;cursor: pointer;letter-spacing: 0.0625em;"><!--[if mso]><i style="mso-font-width:500%;mso-text-raise:60px" hidden>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</i><span style="mso-text-raise:30px;"><![endif]-->My button<!--[if mso]></span><i style="mso-font-width:500%;" hidden>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&#8203;</i><![endif]-->
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

This is 600px wide. I managed to get the Outlook clickable area extending to about 580px. Outlook desktop windows is like a print (PDF) layout, so don't bother trying to make it responsive, just figure out the exact pixels (well... inches and points, it will convert them to!)

It's not the prettiest solution imo but it did do the trick! I modified the code in the if mso tags a bit but now at least it's good enough!
Still don't know what to do with the color of text. I did some digging and it seems like since I have dark mode on Outlook it inverts the color of text. I tried adding a p tag instead of span and I can change text color but then everything else falls apart

you've hit the jackpot of issues in this button it seems! (I'm waiting for rounded corners still!!!) Here's the somewhat also non-pretty solution for keeping text white https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/how-to-fix-outlook-dark-mode-problems--cms-37718t
